# Прекратить бесконечный цикл после нажатия Enter

Tags: python-3.x, input, while

```
while 0 == 0:
    a = 1
    a = input()
    if a == 1:
        print('some text')
    else:
        break
```

Цикл должен выполняться безпрерывно пока я не нажму Enter.
Как убрать прерывания на ввод input() или сделать ввод не обязательным.

Answer (score 1):

я же вам уже отвечал. Если, что-то не понятно, то спросите - что не понятно.

```
a = 1
while a:
    a = input('\nВводите что-нибудь, выход `Enter`: ')
    print('some text ->`{}`'.format(a))
```